# Android SearchView requires two clicks to expand the view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, searchview

Short: When I click on my SearchViewIcon, the SearchView doesn't collapse/expand.

Long:

I"m using a SearchView to filter a RecyclerView in a Fragment that is in my MainActivity.

When I click on the SearchViewIcon (SearchView is iconified by default). I open the tab with the correct Fragment with this code:

```
searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2, false);
            }
        });
```

The Tab with the correct Fragment is opened like expected. Also the text input is shown, but the SearchView stays iconified. (See picture below.)

[Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjnGr.png)

My SearchView in XML:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/menu_item_search_title"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:queryHint="Search name or function"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

Things I already tried:

Setting my showAsAction to always or ifRoom|collapseActionView

```
app:showAsAction="always"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
```

Request focus on my SearchView:

```
searchView.requestFocus();
```

Expanding my SearchViewItem:

```
MenuItem searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
searchViewItem.expandActionView();
```

But non of these things worked...

EDIT
Like the title says, if I click the SearchViewIcon again, the SearchView does expand.

Comment: Did you tried to use MenuItemCompat.expandActionView(searchViewItem) ?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I already tried this.

Answer (score 5):

I've also encountered a similar problem, and was able to solve it.
The main problems I've needed to solve were:

1. searchView was not expanding by default
2. the search EditText didn't get a focus until a second click
3. even after solving (2),  the keyboard didn't show up until a second click

solutions:

1. in menu.xml need to define `app:showAsAction` as `"collapseActionView"` + in java code need also to call `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)` for the expansion to take priority over the iconification (that is - when the icon is pressed, expand and don't stay in icon mode)
2. add a `MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener` for your `search menu-item object`  and use a handler to post a runnable that will request focus to your `search-view object`.
   (why runnable? because requesting focus when the menu is still not fully inflated is not guaranteed to work. When requesting focus in a handler-runnable, I'm making sure the focus request happens AFTER all the work in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is ready and finished.
3. in The same defined runnable from (2), also ask android OS to show the keyboard.

complete code solving all those problems:

> menu.xml:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/searchContacts"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    />
 <!-- and of course your other menu items -->
```

> searchable configuration:

Need to create such xml file.
right-click your `res` folder and choose `new --> android resource file`. put whatever you want as file name ("searchable" will work ok, for example), and choose `XML` as resource type.
Then copy & paste this code in the created file (replace the hint string with your own):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="put here your hint string to be shown"
    />
```

> MainActivity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        implementSearch(menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void implementSearch(final Menu menu) {
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchContacts);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        searchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item){
                // the search view is now open. add your logic if you want
                new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        searchView.requestFocus();
                        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        if (imm != null) { // it's never null. I've added this line just to make the compiler happy
                            imm.showSoftInput(searchView.findFocus(), 0);
                        }


                    }
                });
                return true;
            }


            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item){
                // the search view is closing. add your logic if you want
                return true;
            }

        });

    }
```

Also, if you want to use your own callbacks for the search's text change and submitted (instead of Android intents), in the `implementSearch()` method add a call to `searchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener({...}))`.

view [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850879/do-i-have-to-use-searchable-activity-when-using-androids-searchview/48850880) for more details

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use `always` option for `app:showAsAction`:

`app:showAsAction="always"`

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_search"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
android:title="search"
app:showAsAction="always"
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
/>
```